# Apereo CAS goes to cas overlay (casLoginView.html), is there any way to bypass this page and go straight to a different SSO method?

Tags: groovy, cas

Have a use case where if there are going to a certain URL use a different idp and not cas. Is it possible to redirect them through cas and not display the sign in screen?

Thank you.

Right now I am checking the url in the html and redirecting but I'd rather not go to the html at all.